# Função Retornando Múltiplos Valores no Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

É meu primeiro post nesse forum, então peço desculpas antecipadas por qualquer erro de etiqueta.

Estou tentando implementar uma função em Python 2.7 que me retorna um elemento aleatório de uma lista ou uma sublista de elementos aleatórios de tamanho determinado. Minha ideia para implementação foi essa:

```
def pegaRandom(vetor,k=1):
    n = len(vetor)
    i = randrange(n)
    retorno = vetor[i]
    if k==1:
        return retorno
    else:
        vetor2 = list(vetor)
        vetor2.pop(i)
        return retorno, pegaRandom(vetor2,k-1)
```

Meu comportamento esperado era que a função me retornasse uma sublista quando k>1, mas ao invés disso tenho algo como:

```
>>> pegaRandom(range(1,50),4)
(41, (37, (45, 26)))
>>> pegaRandom(range(1,50),10)
(15, (5, (21, (8, (39, (35, (19, (11, (12, 2)))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonas,

Isso está acontecendo pois quando existem dois ou mais retornos em uma função, o Python retorna todos os dados em um formato de tupla (tuple), veja esse exemplo:

```
def multiploRetorno():
  return 1,2

multiplo = multiploRetorno()

print(type(multiplo), multiplo)
```

https://repl.it/repls/ElderlySimultaneousOutcomes

---

Existe a possibilidade de receber esse retorno em várias variáveis, quando feito dessa forma, o retorno deixa de ser a tupla:

```
def multiploRetorno():
  return 1,2

primeiro, segundo = multiploRetorno()

print(primeiro)
print(segundo)
```

https://repl.it/repls/JoyfulRosyCharacters

---

Portanto como sua função possui dois retornos em recursão, acabam sendo gerada essas tuplas, uma dentro da outra.

---

Para que sua função retorna uma lista quando k > 1, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
from random import randrange

def geraIndiceAleatorio(vetor):
  return randrange(len(vetor))

def pegaRandom(vetor,k=1):
  if k==1:
    return vetor[geraIndiceAleatorio(vetor)]
  else:
    retorno = []
    vetor2 = vetor[:]

    for j in range(k):
      indice = geraIndiceAleatorio(vetor2)
      retorno.append(vetor2[indice])
      vetor2.pop(indice)

    return retorno

print(pegaRandom(range(1,50)))

print(pegaRandom(range(1,50),1))

print(pegaRandom(range(1,50),4))

print(pegaRandom(range(1,50),10))
```

https://repl.it/repls/IdenticalGrippingExperiment

Comment: Obrigado Daniel! A sua implementação com geraIndice me deu uma ideia mais simples, que é simplesmente gerar k números aleatórios entre 0 e len(n)-1 e retornar o vetor. Como o vetor pode ser o mesmo em múltiplas instâncias a chamada recursiva simplesmente adiciona ao vetor. Obrigado!